# Set custom discount price to existing cart/quote in controller

Tags: magento2, module, cart, discount

I know I asked the question once before, but i got no answer, so I try it again and hope for an answer this time. I also saw some other guys that tried to get an answer for this question, but none of them got one, so i need your help.

I would like to set a custom discount price to an existing cart/quote in my controller.

To give you an example, if the customer clicks a button in the cart he will get a random discount price. But now how can I achieve to add this specific disount price to the cart and quote in the controller?

I would appreciate if you could help me with this question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using event. use event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`. Let have an Observer with name AddToCart.php. We would be needing events.xml ofcourse for letting magento2 know.

let makes a file etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="vendor_catalogevent" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Product\CustomOption\PriceRule\Addtocart" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Defining Observer , make a file in Observer/AddToCart.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Product\CustomOption\PriceRule;


use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

/**
 * Class Addtocart
 * @package Vendor\Module\Observer\Product\CustomOption\PriceRule
 */
class Addtocart implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
   */
  protected $_request;

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
   */
  protected $_storeManager;

  /**
   * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
   */
  protected $_product;

  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    )
    {
      $this->_product                 = $product;
      $this->_storeManager            = $storeManager;
      $this->_request                 = $request;
    }

  /**
   * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
   * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
   */
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
      $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
      $percentFactor = 0.2 //giving 20% discount
      $sku = $item->getSku();
      $productCollection = $this->_product->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
      $productPriceBySku = $productCollection->getPrice();
      $customPrice = $productPriceBySku * $percentFactor; // custom price
      $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
      $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
      $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Thank you.

Comment: As I said I want to achieve this in a controller and not in a observer, i found a lot of solutions using an observer, but I just can't use an observer.

Comment: Then you should override ```AddProduct``` function which is present in ```Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart``` and add your logic right before ```checkout_cart_product_add_after``` event dispatch.

Comment: Sorry, but this will also not help